# MS Excel formulae to Concatenate on the basis of string content

Tags: excel

How to write the formula for below sample problem statement-

```
Jack1
Jill1
Mike1
Mike2
Mike3
Dave1
Dave2
Max1
```

This should be written as-

```
Jack1
Jill1
Mike1,2,3
Dave1,2
Max1
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to manipulate data, that data needs to be relatively uniform (the less uniform it is, the more work is required to make it uniform before it can be manipulated.

In this case, I will make the following assumptions about the uniformity of this data:

(1) The number value will always exist; 
(2) The number value will always be at the end of each name;
(3) The number value will always be a single digit;
(4) The number value will always start at 1; and
(5) The names will always be in order.

If any of these assumptions is false, then a VBA solution is required. If they are accurate, then a few helper columns will allow for an Excel formula solution.

Assuming your data is in column A, starting at A1, first use this formula in column B, starting at B1 and dragged down:

```
=right(A1)
```

This pulls the right-most character from each cell in column A. Then put the following formula in column C, starting at C2 and dragged down [C1 will need to be changed to just "=A1"]:

```
=IF(B2=1, A2, C1&","&B2)
```

This will create an arranged list that counts up at each row, until there is a new name. To use this to create a list which only shows the data you want, there are shorter ways but I'll show one of the simpler (but longer) methods:

In D1 and dragged down, put the following formula:

```
=IF(B2=1,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,1),"")
```

This will create a column which increases by 1 each time a new name ends its iteration.

Then in column E (or on a new sheet, or wherever you want your final list to be) put this starting in row 1 and drag down:

```
=IF(ROW()<=MAX(D:D),INDEX(C:C,MATCH(ROW(),D:D,0)),"")
```

This checks the highest number achieved in column D (ie: the number of names so far), and pulls the index in column C (the formatted name) which matches column D for the current row number. ie: if this formula is in ROW 5, and there are at least 5 names listed from column D, then it will match the number 5 from column D, and pull the info from column C where that row matches.